# Efficient way to implement excel import in grails

Tags: excel, grails, groovy, apache-poi

This code should probably go in code review but I won't get quick response there (Only 2 groovy questions there).
I have the following code for importing data from excel into my grails application. The problem is that I didn't test for >1000 rows in the excel file so my app froze when my client tried to upload 13k rows. I have checked the stacktrace.log (app is in production) but no exception. The system admin thinks the jvm ran out of memory. We have increased the size of the heap memory. **However, I want to ask if there's a better way to implement this.** I am using apache poi and creating domain objects as I read each row from excel. After that, I pass the list of objects to the controller that validates and saves them in the database. **Should I tell my client to limit number of items imported at a time?**  **Is there a better way to write this code?**

```
def importData(file, user){
    def rows = []
    def keywords = Keyword.list()
    int inventoryCount = Inventory.findAllByUser(user).size()

    def inventory = new Inventory(name:"Inventory ${inventoryCount +1}", user:user)

    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file)
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)

    int rowStart = 1;
    int rowEnd = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1 ;
    for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
        Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

        if(r != null && r?.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL)!=null ){
            def rowData =[:]
            int lastColumn = 8;
            for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                if (c == null) {
                    return new ExcelFormatException("Empty cell not allowed",rowNum+1, cn+1)
                } else {

                    def field = properties[cn+1]
                    if(field.type==c.getCellType()){
                        if(c.getCellType()==text){

                            rowData<<[(field.name):c.getStringCellValue().toString()]
                        }else if(c.getCellType()==numeric){
                            if(field.name.equalsIgnoreCase("price") ){
                                rowData<<[(field.name):c.getNumericCellValue().toDouble()]
                            }else{
                                rowData<<[(field.name):c.getNumericCellValue().toInteger()]
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        return new ExcelFormatException("Invalid value found", rowNum+1, cn+1)
                    }
                }

            }

            def item = new InventoryItem(rowData)
            String keyword = retrieveKeyword(item.description, keywords)
            String criticality = keyword?"Critical":"Not known"
            int proposedMin = getProposedMin(item.usagePerYear)
            int proposedMax = getProposedMax(proposedMin, item.price, item.usagePerYear, item?.currentMin)
            String inventoryLevel = getInventoryLevel(item.usagePerYear, item.quantity, proposedMin, item.currentMin) 

            item.proposedMin = proposedMin
            item.proposedMax = proposedMax
            item.inventoryLevel = inventoryLevel
            item.keyword = keyword 
            item.criticality = criticality

            inventory.addToItems(item)
        }

    }

    return inventory
}
```

Functions used in above code:

```
def retrieveKeyword(desc, keywords){
    def keyword
    for (key in keywords){
        if(desc.toLowerCase().contains(key.name.toLowerCase())){
            keyword = key.name
            break
        }
    }
    return keyword
}
int getProposedMin(int usage){
    (int) ((((usage/12)/30) *7) + 1)
}


int getProposedMax(int pmin, double price, int usage, int cmin){
    int c = price == 0? 1: ((Math.sqrt((24 * (usage/12)*5)/(0.15*price))) + (pmin - 1))
    if(cmin >= c){
        return pmin
    }
    return c
}

String getInventoryLevel(int usage, int qty, int proposedMin, int currentMin){
    if(qty != 0){
        double c = usage/qty
        if(usage==0)
            return "Excess"
        if(c<0.75){
            return "Inactive"
        }else if(proposedMin<currentMin){
            return "Excess"
        }else if(c>=0.75){
            return "Active"
        }
    }else if(usage==0 && qty == 0){
        return "Not used"
    }else if(usage>3 && qty ==0){
        return "Insufficient"
    }else if(proposedMin > currentMin){
        return "Insufficient"
    }

}
```

Controller action:

```
def importData(){
    if(request.post){
        def file = request.getFile("excelFile")

        //validate file
        def file_types = ["application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"]

        if(!file_types.contains(file.getContentType())){
            render view:"importData", model:[error:"Invalid File type"]
            return
        }

        def inv = excelService.importData(file.getInputStream(),User.get(principal.id))
        if(inv){
            if(inv instanceof ExcelFormatException){
                def err = (ExcelFormatException) inv
                render view:"importData", model:[error:err.message +". Error occurred at: Row: "+err.row+" Col: "+err.col]
                return
            }else{
                render view:"viewData", model:[inventory:inv]
                return
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate and GORM require some tuning when dealing with bulk imports. Two suggestions:

1. Follow the techniques found here: http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql  (written with MySQL in mind, but the concepts are pertinent to any RDBMS)
2. Don't use a collection to map the relationship between `Inventory` and `InventoryItem`.  Remove the `items` collection from `Inventory` and instead add an `Inventory` field to your `InventoryItem` class.  Burt Beckwith covers this in great detail here: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1029

Comment: Do you think its a good idea to implement it in parallel using GPars as seen here > http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/concurrency-and-background ?

Comment: That may be beneficial (depending on the CPU resources available) but I wouldn't start there.  I think you will see a significant performance boost after following the suggestions above.

Answer (score 1):

Using a plugin would be a better option.
I use this plugin - http://grails.org/plugin/excel-import

Comment: I had some issues with it. That's why I wrote mine. However, have you used it on a large data set (>13k rows) before?

Comment: @unekwu Not really. I had to import not more than few hundreds. Can you please report the issue? - http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPXLIMPORT